# How to create references in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

HI Friends please help me...
My first table is create successful and when I create second table with relation then this error is occur.

```
ORA-02270: no matching unique or primary key for this column-list
----------------------------------------------------------------- 
create table abc(
emp_id  number (10),
emp_cnic    number(20),
emp_name    varchar2(50),
primary key(emp_id,emp_cnic));

-----------------------------------------------------------------

create table xyz(
emp_id  number(10),
Att_date    date,
Flag        varchar2(1),
primary key(emp_id),
foreign key (emp_id) references abc(emp_id));

ORA-02270: no matching unique or primary key for this column-list
```

I want two primary keys in first table and foreign key in second table.

Comment: maybe it's beacuse you are using the same name?

Comment: table name should have a meaning

Answer (score 3):

A foreign key must reference a **unique** value (i.e., another primary key or a set of columns that have a unique constraint defined on them).

`emp_id` in your `abc` table is not unique - only the combination of `(emp_id, emp_cnic)` is. Therefore, you cannot reference it with `xyz`'s foreign key.

Comment: `ALTER TABLE some_table ADD CONSTRAINT some_table_uq UNIQUE (column1, column2)`

Answer (score 0):

The foreign key relationship should go in `abc`, not `xyz`:

```
create table xyz (
  emp_id  number(10),
  Att_date    date,
  Flag        varchar2(1),
  primary key(emp_id)
);

create table abc (
  emp_id  number (10),
  emp_cnic    number(20),
  emp_name    varchar2(50),
  primary key(emp_id, emp_cnic),
  foreign key (emp_id) references xyz(emp_id)
);
```

Comment: Thnx its Successfully Done... its mean 1st we create that table which have one primary key means **Unique** and after that we can create references table...

Comment: Gordon, I think you're changing the logic by doing this. I'd rather add a unique key in abc and keep the FK in abc

Comment: @Sebas . . . I'm confused.  You are not the OP.  In any case, foreign keys reference primary keys, not parts of primary keys.

Comment: yes I'm not the OP. You're right about the referencing thing.